# PHP : implementing states with objects

Tags: php, oop

I have a dilemma on how to implement states for objects. 
Let's say we have this:

```
class User {

     private $_active;// 1 or 0
     private $_deleted;// 1 or 0
     ...

}
```

These properties - as I see it - imply a state on User object. 
What I would like to do is to define some events like afterActivate() or afterDelete() so I can chain my routines. I.e. after activation update some counters, after deletion also update some counters...

So I'm considering two approaches at the moment - first one is to create classes Activable and Deletable ( don't mind the naming ) and then make User inherit those classes through a hierarchy of inheritance.

```
class Activable {

    protected afterActivate(){};

}

class Deletable {

    protected afterDelete(){};
}

class Activable extends Deletable {}
class User extends Activable{}
```

There are two problems that I see with this approach - first one is that class Activable now has implied Deletable state which is wrong and second problem is - if I have more states - 5-6 states the inheritance hierarchy may become quite complex. ( because User will extend the model class which will extend something else etc...)

The second approach is to use traits in PHP and use them to achieve this.
So I would have something like

```
class User{
    use Activable, Deletable; 

}
```

What approach would be better - maybe some 3rd approach? 
Am I going in the right direction here?

Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you would use [`Marker Interface`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern)s  for this sort of thing.
I suppose this is some kind of ORM we're talking about? Than I also assume there is some kind of object handling the persistence of your entities. Let that object check that `$entity instanceof Deletable` and act upon that.

Comment: Since your answer is the only one and Marker Interface is a viable solution, I'll accept it as the correct answer.